# javarscript "mutable variable is accesible from closure" in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, mutable

Im trying to assign a function to every button inside an array.

to simplify the problem i have exchanged the functionality of that function with a simple console.log

When one of the buttons is clicked the console is supposed to say "button number" and then the according button number (1, 2, 3...) Instead it always returns the maximum button number.

```
        function buttoncount(){
            dbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("deletebutton");
            for(var ii = 0; ii< dbuttons.length; ii++){
                dbuttons[ii].onclick = function (){
                    console.log("button number"+ii);
                }
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I would assume that it's returning the value of ii rather than the index of that particular button. If you assign ii to a local variable and output that instead, you should get the result you expect.

i.e. `var index = ii; console.log('button number' + index`

Comment: nope, didnt fix anything

Comment: Yes, my apologies--I was imagining a clojure that didn't actually exist. Here's a fiddle in jQuery that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/md9b8/6/

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ensure that separate closures are caught for consecutive buttons. One of the ways is always to wrap the actual function within another one that is immediately executed.

```
    function buttoncount(){
        dbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("deletebutton");
        for(var ii = 0; ii< dbuttons.length; ii++){
            dbuttons[ii].onclick = (function (x){
                return function() {
                  console.log("button number"+x);
                }
            }(ii));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think of just one closure context with the same `ii` shared between all functions in your aproach versus separate objects that capture current value of `ii` in my approach. A closure is created to catch the structural scope. If the scope doesn't change, the same closure is reused (your approach).